# How to mock JmsTemplate with Mockito?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test

I try to test a class where i send a jms message but i can't mock the JmsTemplate

**JmsProducer.class :**

```
@Component
public class JmsProducer {

@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

@Value("${destination}")
private String destination;

public void send(String message){
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destination, message);
}
}
```

**JmsProducerTest.Class :**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class JmsProducerTest {

private static final String DESTINATION= "example";
private static final String MESSAGE= "message";

@InjectMocks
private JmsProducer jmsProducer;

@MockBean
JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

@Before
public void init(){
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(jmsProducer, "destinationQueue", DESTINATION);
}

@Test
public void testsend(){
    jmsProducer.send(MESSAGE);
    verify(jmsTemplate,times(1)).convertAndSend(DESTINATION, MESSAGE);
}
}
```

And when i run this test case it gives me : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

Have you any idea for this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also notice that it could not Mock JmsTemplate and ObjectMapper too  with jdk 1.8.05 and when i change the JDK to 1.8.74 it works nice.

I referenced to the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41050029/mockito-cannot-mock-this-class?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `SpringRunner` you should add to the `init` method `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`, because `@InjectMocks` will be work  correct with `MockitoJUnitRunner`.

PS. `ReflectionTestUtils.setField(jmsProducer, "destinationQueue", DESTINATION);` - but your fields have another name - `destination`, not `destinationQueue`