# Mockito error in Spring Boot tests after migrating to JDK 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I have just migrated to JDK 11 in order to use the latest Java LTS version. If I change the execution JRE in Eclipse from 10 to 11 (and only then), when I try to run my tests, I get the following exception stacktrace.

Please note that everything works as expected if I switch back to jdk-10. I use Spring Boot and my tests also use Mockito. My pom.xml is also shown here.

Is there a known incompatibility between Spring Boot and/or Mockito with jdk-11? Perhaps another reference missing in pom.xml?

pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- update Hibernate dependency on Javassist to 3.23.1 for Java 11 compatibility -->
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class org.foo.MockedClass.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 11
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 11+28
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 11+28
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Linux
OS version         : 4.4.0-128-generic


Underlying exception : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockDefinition.createMock(MockDefinition.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor.createMock(MockitoPostProcessor.java:222)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor.registerMock(MockitoPostProcessor.java:192)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor.register(MockitoPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(MockitoPostProcessor.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(MockitoPostProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:282)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$Unavailable.defineClass(ClassInjector.java:821)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection.inject(ClassInjector.java:185)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$InjectionDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:187)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:79)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4457)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(SubclassBytecodeGenerator.java:121)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:37)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:34)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:138)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:346)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:161)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:355)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:71)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:42)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:25)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:65)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1855)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find sun.misc.Unsafe
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe$Dispatcher$Disabled.initialize(ClassInjector.java:1366)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe.inject(ClassInjector.java:1202)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$ForUnsafeInjection.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:458)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:79)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4457)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$Indirect.make(ClassInjector.java:684)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$CreationAction.run(ClassInjector.java:302)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$CreationAction.run(ClassInjector.java:290)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection.<clinit>(ClassInjector.java:70)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$InjectionDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:184)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String, [B, int, int, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.security.ProtectionDomain)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2109)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe$Dispatcher$CreationAction.run(ClassInjector.java:1269)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe$Dispatcher$CreationAction.run(ClassInjector.java:1257)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe.<clinit>(ClassInjector.java:1136)
    ... 74 more
```

Comment: What is are the versions of mockito and bytebuddy ? I believe Bytebuddy introduced **preliminary** Java 11 support in 1.8.0, however I advise you to try with the latest bytebuddy version in this regard (as of today [1.8.22](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/releases/latest))

Comment: Spring Boot 2.0 (and related Spring 5.0) doesn't, officially, support JDK 11. So don't upgrade.

Comment: Doesn't JDK 11 reduce/change the operation of reflection quite significantly; which would have an impact on Spring (boot)?

Comment: Haven't spotted any issues so far with Spring Boot 2 and Java 11.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Was the same problem.
Add Mockito 2.22.0 to dependencies. Everything seems to work.

```
compile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.22.0'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Everything works as expected now. Adding the link to the respective maven reference to facilitate others finding it: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.22.0

Comment: FYI: 2.19.1 is the version in which this got fixed (of course 2.22.0 also works :)). Thanks!

Comment: this is totally weird, 2.22.0 works just fine. but the latest version doesn't seem to

Comment: I had thought the latest wasn't either, but after a good clean and rebuild, Mockito 2.23.4 worked

Comment: I had same problem with Java 11.  specifying  <version>2.22.0</version> in mockito dependency solved  it. Found solution at https://dev.to/scottshipp/how-to-fix-a-mockito-cannot-mock-this-class-exception-in-a-spring-boot-app-457e

Comment: Thanks, I've checked different sources and nothing was working. I am currently with Java 13 and was using the latest version of Mockito. When I downgraded it to 2.22.0, it started working fine.

Comment: This answer was helpful except I needed version Mockito version 3.1.0. 
 I used sonatype's site to look for my spring boot's most recent compatible version, just click your version and find your dependency version: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies