# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String, [B, int, int, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.security.ProtectionDomain)

Tags: maven, mockito, google-cloud-dataflow, maven-surefire-plugin, google-cloud-build

I have a problem While running `mvn test` on Google cloud build ( `gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn` )  The errors message like this

```
Step #2 - "Test": org.apache.beam.runners.direct.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection
Step #2 - "Test": Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection
Step #2 - "Test": Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find sun.misc.Unsafe
Step #2 - "Test": Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String, [B, int, int, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.security.ProtectionDomain)
```

I don't know why it happened because I don't know which dependencies caused the error

This is my pom.xml file looks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ~ Copyright (C) 2017 Google Inc.
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  ~ use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
  ~ the License at
  ~
  ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
  ~ WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
  ~ License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
  ~ the License.
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <bigquery.version>v2-rev374-1.22.0</bigquery.version>
    <google-clients.version>1.23.0</google-clients.version>
    <guava.version>20.0</guava.version>
    <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
    <joda.version>2.4</joda.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <exec-maven-plugin.version>1.6.0</exec-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.0.2</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    <maven-shade-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-shade-plugin.version>
    <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
    <pubsub.version>v1-rev10-1.22.0</pubsub.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M1</surefire-plugin.version>
    <jackson.version>2.9.4</jackson.version>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.kuali.maven.wagons</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <parallel>all</parallel>
          <threadCount>4</threadCount>
          <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <finalName>${project.artifactId}-bundled-${project.version}</finalName>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>${google-clients.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-cloudkms</artifactId>
      <version>v1-rev71-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-bigquery</artifactId>
      <version>${bigquery.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
      <version>${google-clients.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-pubsub</artifactId>
      <version>${pubsub.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>${joda.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
      <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>${mockito.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have followed from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533878/mockito-error-in-spring-boot-tests-after-migrating-to-jdk-11), was not works for my case

is there anyone know how to solve the problem like this ?