# Mockito cannot mock this class: interface org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to test one of service class in my spring boot application. The service class has `ElasticsearchOperations` bean injected in it. But I'm facing issue when trying to mock this bean in my testclass. Getting following error in test case:

```html
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: interface org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations.

If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 11
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 11.0.2+9
JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 11.0.2+9
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Mac OS X
OS version         : 10.15.7


You are seeing this disclaimer because Mockito is configured to create inlined mocks.
You can learn about inline mocks and their limitations under item #39 of the Mockito class javadoc.

Underlying exception : org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes [interface org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.SearchOperations, interface org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations, interface org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.DocumentOperations]
    at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.beforeEach(MockitoExtension.java:153)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$2(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:162)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:129)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.afterEach(MockitoExtension.java:184)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterEachCallbacks$12(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:257)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:273)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$14(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:273)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:272)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAfterEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:256)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:141)
        ... 68 more
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes [interface org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.SearchOperations, interface org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations, interface org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.DocumentOperations]
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:153)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:366)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:175)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:377)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Byte Buddy could not instrument all classes within the mock's type hierarchy

This problem should never occur for javac-compiled classes. This problem has been observed for classes that are:
 - Compiled by older versions of scalac
 - Classes that are part of the Android distribution
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.triggerRetransformation(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:176)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:152)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:37)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:34)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:153)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:366)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:175)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:377)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:199)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:180)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:63)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1908)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotationForMock(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:44)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:19)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:39)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:63)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:58)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:42)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:68)
    at org.mockito.internal.framework.DefaultMockitoSession.<init>(DefaultMockitoSession.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.session.DefaultMockitoSessionBuilder.startMocking(DefaultMockitoSessionBuilder.java:78)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.AliasMetaData not present
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.computeReturnType(MethodRepository.java:75)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:66)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:292)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$LazyProjection$ForLoadedReturnType.resolve(TypeDescription.java:6543)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$LazyProjection.accept(TypeDescription.java:6129)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription$AbstractBase.asToken(MethodDescription.java:873)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription$AbstractBase.asToken(MethodDescription.java:435)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodList$AbstractBase.asTokenList(MethodList.java:87)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.InstrumentedType$Factory$Default$1.represent(InstrumentedType.java:421)
    at net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy.redefine(ByteBuddy.java:782)
    at net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy.redefine(ByteBuddy.java:757)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.transform(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:249)
    at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:246)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:563)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:167)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.triggerRetransformation(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:173)
    ... 98 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.AliasMetaData
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    ... 121 more
```

The test class looks like:

```html
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    MyServiceImpl serviceImpl;

    @Mock
    ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations;

    @Mock
    IndexNameUtil indexNameUtil;

    @Test
    void test_saveEntities() {
        when(indexNameUtil.getIndex()).thenReturn("test");
        doNothing().when(elasticsearchOperations.save(any(), any()));
        serviceImpl.save(getEntityListMock());
        verify(elasticsearchOperations, times(1)).save(any(), any());
    }
  
  List<Obj> getEntityListMock() {
  //returns list of dummy objects
  }

}
```

// Nothing fancy, just simple verification of save method being called

**What I have tried:**

- [Mockito cannot mock this class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41050029/mockito-cannot-mock-this-class)
- Updating versions of mockito-inline to newer/older ones

**Dependencies Used:**

`mockito-inline::3.11.2`

`java version:: openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15`

`spring-data-elasticsearch:: 4.0.0.RELEASE`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stacktrace I see

> Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.AliasMetaData not present

Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0.0.RELEASE was built against Elasticsearch libraries 7.6.2 and this class is found in the elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar

Do you explicitly use a different Elasticsearch library version? This class is in the library since version 6.2.