# Junit Error : Invoking the beforeTestMethod method on PowerMock test listener

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am facing JUnit jar compatibility issue.initially, when I had created my JUnit classes below are the main jar versions.

```
springframework.boot.version 1.3.0.RELEASE
Mock - mockito-core-1.10.19.jar
Power mockito - powermock-module-junit4-1.6.4.jar
                 powermock-api-mockito-1.6.4.jar
```

Now we have upgraded spring boot version to 2.0.0.RELEASE and maven build is falling with below error

```
Tests in error:
 initializationError(com.amit.Test.TestStudent): org/mockito/cglib/proxy/Enhancer
 testAddress(com.amit.test.TestAddressProcess): Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
```

I tried below answer and changed powermock-api-mockito to powermock-api-mockito2
[Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956692/could-not-initialize-plugin-interface-org-mockito-plugins-mockmaker/47294653#47294653)

but getting below error

```
testAddress((com.amit.test.TestAddressProcess): Invoking the beforeTestMethod method on PowerMock test listener org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler@22277482 failed.
```

Updated versions are

```
springframework.boot.version 2.0.0.RELEASE
Mock - mockito-core-2.15.0.jar
Power mockito - powermock-module-junit4-2.0.0.jar
                 powermock-api-mockito-2.0.0.jar
```

Kindly help if anyone else face the same issue with jar versions

**Complete Stack trace**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Invoking the beforeTestMethod method on PowerMock test listener org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler@5b69d40d failed.
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:84)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:308)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class 
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.

 Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
  If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 1.8
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 25.0-b70
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 1.8.0-b132
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Windows 8.1
OS version         : 6.3


Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.standardInject(AnnotationEnabler.java:98)
at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:55)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:82)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$AnnotationReader$ForTypeArgument.resolve(TypeDescription.java:3451)
at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$AnnotationReader$Delegator$Chained.resolve(TypeDescription.java:3234)
at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$AnnotationReader$ForTypeArgument.resolve(TypeDescription.java:3424)
at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$AnnotationReader$Delegator.asList(TypeDescription.java:3186)
at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfNonGenericType$ForLoadedType.getDeclaredAnnotations(TypeDescription.java:3872)
at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.AnnotationAppender$ForTypeAnnotations.apply(AnnotationAppender.java:669)
at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.AnnotationAppender$ForTypeAnnotations.onNonGenericType(AnnotationAppender.java:650)
at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.AnnotationAppender$ForTypeAnnotations.onNonGenericType(AnnotationAppender.java:353)
at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfNonGenericType.accept(TypeDescription.java:3662)
at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.AnnotationAppender$ForTypeAnnotations.onParameterizedType(AnnotationAppender.java:627)
at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.AnnotationAppender$ForTypeAnnotations.onParameterizedType(AnnotationAppender.java:353)
at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfParameterizedType.accept(TypeDescription.java:4976)
at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.MethodAttributeAppender$ForInstrumentedMethod.apply(MethodAttributeAppender.java:193)
at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.MethodAttributeAppender$Compound.apply(MethodAttributeAppender.java:449)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyAttributes(TypeWriter.java:691)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyBody(TypeWriter.java:681)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod.apply(TypeWriter.java:590)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForCreation.create(TypeWriter.java:5114)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:1915)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:197)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:174)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:3376)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase$Delegator.make(DynamicType.java:3565)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(SubclassBytecodeGenerator.java:128)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:37)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:34)
at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:137)
at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:350)
at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:159)
at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:361)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:32)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:71)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:42)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:25)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.createMock(PowerMockMaker.java:41)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:69)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1895)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(DefaultMockCreator.java:108)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.doCreateMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:61)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:53)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.mock(DefaultMockCreator.java:40)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:181)
... 27 more
```

Comment: Can you please share the full stacktrace?

Comment: Please See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi @Morfic - I am not able to add complete trace in comment section due to length issue

Comment: Do not add it as a comment as the space is limited and also it'd be unreadable. Instead edit your question, and append it there.

Comment: Hi @Morfic - Thanks have added complete stack trace

Comment: This looks like a clear duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527038/mockito-object-is-not-an-instance-of-declaring-class. Can you try using a newer JDK version?

Comment: Thanks @Morfic, I have upgraded my Java to 1.8.81 version and now things are working fine

Comment: Great, have fun! I guess we can close this as a duplicate after all